# Adding elements without br in razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to know how can I add elements to page without breaking line

Now I have a piece of code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TagModels)
    { 

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Name)
        </div>

    }
```

which adds me inputs to page, but with breaking line.

I want to have it in one row. Could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TagModels)
{ 

    <div class="editor-field" style="float: left">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Name)
    </div>

}
```

The float property in CSS is used for alignment. This would place all the divs in one line. Each DIV is added to the right of the previous DIV

Answer (score 2):

It's the `div` container that your inputs are in that are causing them to appear below each other. Just remove the `div` or replace it with a `span` or `display:inline`

Answer (score 1):

The validationmessage is probably a div. Try changing the CSS to display:inline